# Could things go in vain? Or they just were in vain?

Tags: vocabulary, british-english

What verb usually goes with "in vain"? Just "to be" or any other?

Comment: Have you looked at [definitions](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+vain)? Or [here](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-vain)

Comment: My guess would be that "to be" is most common, followed very closely by "to try."  Many other verbs could work very well. (Struggled, toiled, labored, attempted, called, etc, etc, etc.)

Comment: Anything that can be done could be done in vain.  This seems akin to asking what verb usually goes with "on the floor"-  They laid on the floor, they jumped on the floor, they danced on the floor...

Comment: @Adam
I shouldve been more specific. Yes, "to be" seems natural, something was in vain, but I was trying to ask, as per title: can u say that sth goes/went in vain?

Comment: [These example sentences](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/vain) might be helpful in understanding the different ways "in vain" can be used. Some of those sentences use just "vain", and the meaning can be different, so not all of the sentences apply to your question.

Comment: Yes, it can be used with goes : "I went to the mountaintop in vain; the guru wasn't there." You may want to edit your question to include the information in your comment to make it very clear what you're asking.

Comment: @Colleen - thanks a lot! Just done it. So, "I dont want sth to go in vain" - thats correct, isnt it?

Comment: Can't say it really improved the question, tbh.

Comment: @Tetsujin I agree - I was hoping the question would have more information not less. This thread on the meta site might be helpful: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/439/9161

Answer (score 3):

*In vain* is ordinarily an adverbial, describing the outcome of an "agentive" verb, one which represents action performed by someone:

> He labored in vain to finish before the deadline.

Consequently it is employed as a predicative adjectival only when the subject is an NP representing an action:

> His efforts were in vain.

But when the noun represents a stative verb, *in vain* comes off very oddly:

> <sup>?</sup> His knowledge was in vain.

And it doesn't work at all with nouns of other sorts:

> <sup>*</sup> His car was in vain.

Comment: I believe @Jack wanted to confirm that "to go" goes naturally with "in vain." In this sense [the other answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/55367/1812) comes a little bit closer to what was asked. Although your answer sheds some light on other not in any way nonrelevant or uninteresting topics :) As the one coming here with this particular question in mind, let me add an example, "I couldn't let this chance go in vain (slip by)." No pun intended :)

Answer (score 2):

"In vain" can be used as an adverb meaning "unsuccessfully", or "pointlessly". For example, a common catch-phrase is, "We labored in vain". That is, we did a bunch of work but it accomplished nothing.

"In vain" can also be used as an adjective, almost always as a predicate adjective. "Our labor was in vain".

As Jim says in the comments, almost anything you could do could be done "in vain". "I begged her to forgive me in vain", "I searched for the lost key in vain", "I tried to explain the grammar rules in vain", etc. Whether any given verb would make sense would, of course, depend on the context and the situatin.

So you could, "Go in vain" if you mean, you went to some destination but the effort was unsuccessful, either because you couldn't get there or because once you got there you could not accomplish whatever it was you were trying to do. Like, "You can try to travel to Boston to find your sister. But you will GO IN VAIN, because even if you find her she won't speak to you."

If you want to use "go" in the sense of "become", I don't think that would be idiomatic English. That is, you can't say, "This is going in vain" meaning "this is becoming pointless", that's just not how the words are used.